# Save rendered images in different formats

Tags: rendering, file-format

When I try to save the rendered image, all I get is a *.png picture format. **Can I save in other formats *(.jpeg .bmp .gif)* straight from Blender? How ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [*Output* panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Output#Output_Panel) in the [render settings](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render#The_Render_Settings_Panel). It can also be changed post render with *Image > Save As Image* (<kbd>F3</kbd>) in the *Save As Image* side panel.

If you want to output to multiple formats, this can be done using the [*File Output* compositor node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Output#File_Output_Node).

For GIF see: [Can Blender render animated gifs?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1934/290)