# How to convert image textures to different formats?

Tags: image, file-format, conversion

I used Blender to export a 3D model in X3D format. However, textures are automatically exported in TGA format. In order to print multicolor models in Shapeways (https://www.shapeways.com), the requirement is to provide textures in JPG or GIF format. Is there any way to do this in Blender or any other tool?

Answer (score 3):

In the **UV/image Editor** select the texture or image you want to convert and press <kbd>F3</kbd> (or Image->Save As),

[image]

Then select which format you want to save as.

(If you don't see these options on the left side of the screen press <kbd>T</kbd>.)

[image]

**NOTE: [Gif files are not supported in blender.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/can-blender-render-animated-gifs)**.

see http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Formats