# Can't export UV Map Collada

Tags: export, collada

When I export my Blender file to collada file. The image texture is not exported. I tried all possible export options. Does anyone of you guys have an idea why I can't get a collada file which is textured?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This is a different format - so while the answer may be useful/apply, this question is not technically a duplicate.

Comment: Did you try baking the texture? That will create a file with the image texture. All you have to do then is save the image as a file.

Comment: Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14953/how-to-convert-image-textures-to-different-formats